# Multiple delimiters using Regex.Split in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say you need to split a string by various delimiters including newline (/r, /n) and a few other 'special' character strings.

For example:

```
This is a sample %%% text &&& that I would 
like to split %%% into an array.
```

I would like the following in the resulting string array (contents via index)

```
[0]This is a sample
[1]text
[2]that I would
[3]like to split
[4]into an array.
```

I would like to use C# Regex.Split() function.  What is the regex expression to match on all of my delimiters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just FYI, the vanilla String.Split() method has an overload which accepts an array of strings to use as delimiters.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) a link to MSDN's page describing it.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I missed this one.  This solved my extra blank entry issue.

Answer (score 8):

`%%%|&&&` should do it.

Comment: Also, you could use @"[\r\n...insert characters here...]+" to eliminate splitting multiple times if separators are neighbors. Or @"[\r\n]" to split even if neighbors.

Comment: Thanks I think I'm almost there.  I'm only having an issue where there is an extra (blank) entry in my string array for these delimiters.

Comment: I went with Eric's solution but I'm sure I just had this wrong somewhere.  Thanks Dave and Fredrik.