# Regex To Split On Specific Word and Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to add a specific word 'and' to my existing split regex along with other symbols. so that split works on 'and' or ',' and other symbols along with specific word.

```
var searchStrings = phrase.split(/[ ,&]/);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967594/multiple-delimiters-using-regex-split-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try

- reading up on [javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and
- Fiddling around with a javascript regular expression sandbox like https://regex101.com/

However, you might try something like

```
const words = 'this & that, or maybe red and blue'
              .split(/[,&]|and/i );
              ;
```

The above returns

```
[
  'this '          ,
  ' that'          ,
  ' or maybe red ' ,
  ' blue'
]
```

I believe that should do you.